# Flex item same width as children

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a container element, a flex item, the same width as it's span text child. As you can see by inspecting the result from the snippet, although the container `.calc-text-container` takes up more space than the child element does, even though the flex-grow-property is set to 0.

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

```css
.calc {
  width: 230px;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.calc a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.calc-icon-container {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.calc-text-container {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  background: rgba(20,200,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="calc-icon-container"><span class="calc-icon"></span></div>
 <div class="calc-text-container"><span class="calc-text">To do something megagiga</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in your demo. Can you provide more details? Or an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Just flex: 0 0 0; will do the job.

```css
.calc {
  width: 230px;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.calc a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.calc-icon-container {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.calc-text-container {
  flex: 0 0 0; // or just flex: 0;
  background: rgba(20,200,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="calc-icon-container"><span class="calc-icon"></span></div>
 <div class="calc-text-container"><span class="calc-text">Reallylongword Short shortandlong</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will not allow a sentence that can fit on one line to be on one line - setting the flex basis to 0 will attempt to always wrap the text.